# How to stop a currently running cron job?

Tags: cron

How can I stop a cron job which is currently running?

Comment: The three answers below interpret this question in three ways. @GURU, could you please clarify what you would like to do? Would you like to kill a process started by cron that is now running, or would you like to prevent the job running in the future?

Answer (score 45):

You can do this the same way you'd stop any process.

To stop a currently running `cron` job, you can do one of the following:

```
pkill process-name
```

or if you know the PID (you can determine it by running `ps`):

```
kill 1234
```

(substituting the actual PID)

Comment: how to list which currently running cron jobs ?

Comment: @UWU_SANDUN: You can use `pgrep` or `grep` the output of `ps`. There's nothing special about a process run from `cron`. You would just search for the process under its own name. You can also do `ps fauxww | grep -A 1 '[C]RON'` and lines below the line(s) will show jobs being run by `cron`. You can adjust the number 1 higher to see subprocesses if any.

Comment: Note you must be running cygwin as admin to kill processes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090301/6854489) for more info on that.

Comment: Using Ubuntu I typed what @takanuva15 suggested, `ps fauxww | grep -A 1 '[C]RON'`. This lists the current cron jobs running, so thereafter you can note the PID down and execute `# kill -9 PID`. Thanks!

Comment: @russellhoff: `-9` should only be used as a last resort because it prevents the process from doing any cleanup as it exits.

Comment: On mac I needed to do `ps -A` to show the cron job

Answer (score 28):

Strange, no one has mentioned this method:

```
$ crontab -e
```

In the opened editor, delete line of the task you want to stop or insert a `#` sign, save and exit

e.g.

before

```
* * * * * some_script1
* * * * * some_script2
```

after

```
* * * * * some_script1
#* * * * * some_script2
```

or

```
* * * * * some_script1
```

restart the service after making changes by

```
sudo service cron reload
```

Comment: This doesn't stop a currently running cron job, it stops future cron jobs that will be launch by cron.

Answer (score 21):

To stop running cron job .First get the process id of your command with

`top -p $(pgrep -d',' your_command)`

eg:-

`top -p $(pgrep -d',' httpd)`

and run

`kill PID` replace `PID` with process id

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Redhat (RHEL)/Fedora Core/Cent OS Linux use the following command :

```
/etc/init.d/crond stop
```

If you are using Debian or Ubuntu Linux the following command :

```
/etc/init.d/cron stop
```

P.S : You should be root to do these things

Comment: i think  it stops all crons .to stop particular cron may i know the command

Comment: can u pls suggest any command sen

Comment: I dont think it is possible in a straight way.. Maybe we should go for a hack.

Comment: This stops the `crond` daemon, does it also stop anything it spawned?  You also generally always want `crond` running on a typical Linux system; there's a lot that usually depends on it running.

Answer (score 10):

First type `ps aux` to see what all processes are running.

Then note down the `PID` of each process you want to stop

Then type

`kill {PID`} for each process.

Also do have a look at these links (superuser links) :

[Verify-that-a-cron-job-has-completed](https://superuser.com/questions/125697/verify-that-a-cron-job-has-completed)

[ps-aux-output-meaning](https://superuser.com/questions/117913/ps-aux-output-meaning)

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the cron table and comment out the task in question. Switch to the user that controls the task, export your editor of choice into the environment, then use `crontab -l`:

```
$ su - root
...
# EDITOR=vi; export EDITOR
# crontab -l
```

Comment: That lists the crontab. Use `crontab -e` to edit it. For systems that have it, it's preferable to use `sudo` instead of `su`. Also, `crontab -e` would work for the user (or root) crontab, but not the system crontab (e.g. `/etc/cron*`).

Answer (score 2):

#### If you want to remove all the crontabs that are running (the commands will be lost):

```
crontab -r
```

#### ... or If you want to stop some commands on crontab:

1. Open crontab to edit:

```
 crontab -e
```

2. Comment the commands in the crontab that needs to be stopped and save it. You can comment using '#'.

Answer (score 2):

This is my take on this, which I use from time to time.

First, let's find the process IDs of the processes cron has started by using:

```
systemctl status cron
```

This will give you a nice little process tree.

Each process' ID are the numbers displayed to the left of the process' name.

So, if my process ID for a process started by cron is 2234225, then I'll simply go:

```
kill 2234225
```

I can check either with:

```
systemctl status cron
```

or

```
top
```

that the process has been terminated.

Just remember, if the process in question is set to be started as defined by the crontab

```
crontab -e
```

then, the process in question will become activated again, just with a different process ID.

Comment: Something like `ps ax | grep $PID` is far more functional than using top to check for processes, especially when there are more than a dozen.

Answer (score 1):

Working for me for linux

```
pkill -9 crontab
```

Kills all process having process name **crontab**

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the working process with this command.

```
ps -o pid,sess,cmd afx | egrep "( |/)cron( -f)?$"
```

This command's output is

```
599  599 cron
4288  599 \_ CRON
```

and now kill the process with this command

```
pkill -s 4288
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Redhat (RHEL)/Fedora Core/Cent OS Linux use the following command :

$ sudo systemctl status crond

If you are using Debian or Ubuntu Linux the following command :

$ sudo systemctl status cron